# how to store a Jpeg file in a database?

Tags: database, web-applications, jakarta-ee

Is it possible to store a Jpeg file in a database using a Web Application?

can you share some code on how to do it?

or share some links for some tutorial regarding with my problem? thanks a lot :)

Comment: Couldn't you just store the location of the file in the database and upload the file elsewhere?

Comment: asked a million times. Search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[storing an image in a blob](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Database/JDBC20Intro/exercises/BLOBPut/index.html)

i don't use java, i don't know what database structure you are using but the principle is to store the image in a binary large object. (blob) it does require reading the object in and out using streams. (or at least in c# this is the case)

the alternative(if it works) is to store a string location and have the image in a directory somewhere.

Comment: I think you didn't read my answer carefully. You should read what scenario I have talked about.

Comment: Don't down vote an answer that works because i don't agree with your statement. At least i had the decency to tell you why, and was not the only one

Answer (score 0):

BLOB data type, that is what u need.

and the link is ;)

[blob google search](http://www.google.com.vn/search?hl=en&client=opera&hs=aDW&rls=en&channel=suggest&q=blob+jpg+mysql&aq=f&aqi=g-b1&aql=&oq=)

Answer (score -1):

This is not a good practice to store a jpeg file in database. Always store the file in related directories and store their paths in your database. If you are storing jpeg files in your database, then think about the size of your database if you are having 1 million records?

Comment: i'm afraid that really depends on the circumstances, if that was the case why would a blob field exist?